# CGContextAddPath: invalid context 0x0

Tags: ios, button

At first: No the CGRect is not empty (I literally searched the whole web and got to know about every possible way to fix it but it seems that I wasn't successful so far)

RqButton.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface RqButton : UIButton
@property (nonatomic) int c;
@property (nonatomic) float r;
@property (nonatomic) float g;
@property (nonatomic) CGRect frame;

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame c:(int)c;
@end
```

RqButton.m

```
#import "RqButton.h"
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

@implementation RqButton

+ (RqButton *)buttonWithType:(UIButtonType)type
{return [super buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];}


- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame c:(int)c
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self)
    {   self.r=c%16;
        self.g=c/16;

        [self drawRect:frame];
    }
    return self;
}


- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    float width =  CGRectGetWidth(rect);
    float height =  CGRectGetHeight(rect);

    UIColor *borderColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.05f green:0.05f blue:0.05f alpha:1.00f];
    NSLog(@"%f",width);

    CGFloat BGLocations[2] = { 0.0, 1.0 };
    CGFloat BgComponents[8] = { self.r*0.33f, self.g*0.33f, 0.0f , 1.0,
        0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 1.0 };
    CGColorSpaceRef BgRGBColorspace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    CGGradientRef bgRadialGradient = CGGradientCreateWithColorComponents(BgRGBColorspace, BgComponents, BGLocations, 2);

    UIBezierPath *roundedRectanglePath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect: CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height) cornerRadius: 5];
    [roundedRectanglePath addClip];

    CGPoint startBg = CGPointMake (width*0.5, height*0.5);
    CGFloat endRadius= 32;

    CGContextDrawRadialGradient(ctx, bgRadialGradient, startBg, 0, startBg, endRadius, kCGGradientDrawsAfterEndLocation);
    CGColorSpaceRelease(BgRGBColorspace);
    CGGradientRelease(bgRadialGradient);

    [borderColor setStroke];
    roundedRectanglePath.lineWidth = 2;
    [roundedRectanglePath stroke];

}

@end
```

Calling the class like this

```
int xz=  buttons[x][y].frame.origin.x;
        int yz=  buttons[x][y].frame.origin.y;

        buttons[x][y] = [[RqButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(xz, yz, 30, 30) c:(int)51  ];
        [buttons[x][y] addTarget:self action:@selector(actionPick:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
        buttons[x][y].tag = tag;

        [self.view addSubview:buttons[x][y]];
```

I can't just ignore the error as my app is totally freezing some times. I need to do all that to customise the look of my buttons. Applying the Class to the Button by .xib works perfectly fine.

This

```
Error>: CGContextAddPath: invalid context 0x0. This is a serious error. This application, or a library it uses, is using an invalid context
```

is coming for many CG methods; CGContextDrawRadialGradient: clip; CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor: CGContextSaveGState: CGContextSetLineWidth: [...]

Thanks a lot in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can't call drawRect yourself like that. The OS calls your drawRect method when it is time to draw, and only after it has set up the environment for your class to draw into. This is why there is a crash. 
If you want to force a draw to happen soon, call [self setNeedsDisplay].

Comment: It happens on a button click and if I do it by the "original" initWithFrame, everything is working fine. Just when I have to set my "own" initWithFrame in order to pass the parameters to the class, everything breaks. 
Where am I supposed to put  [self setNeedsDisplay]; ? I tried but it didn't make it any better ..

Comment: You don't supply enough of the code to see what else is going on (e.g. none of the code that is called in response to a click), but you should not be calling drawRect from your init method, as that definitely can cause the context error you are seeing. You also shouldn't be declaring a property called "frame" because that class already has one (inherited from UIButton > UIControl > UIView).